# How to count number of divisible terms without using modulus operator?

Tags: algorithm, math, modulus, integer-division

Given three numbers N, A and B. Find how integers in range from 1 to N are divisible by A or B. I can't use modulus operator from range 1 to N because N can be as large as 10^12 and then I would run out of allocated time for the program to produce an output. I have tried formulating the equation but couldn't come up with a solution.

**Input Constraints:=**

```
1<=N<=10^12
1<=A<=10^5
1<=B<=10^5
```

Comment: This is exactly the point of this challenge, I guess..

Comment: Sounds like a sieve could help here, but it is hard to say what would work best for you without your allocated time constraint.

Comment: I just want to use some equation to evaluate this thing rather than a modulus operator because the program needs to produce results within 1 sec. I have tried this `counter=(((int)(N/A))+((int)(N/B)))-((int)(N/(A*B)));` but it fails for input N=200 A=20 B=8

Comment: The last factor `N/(A*B)` is incorrect. You are not looking for `A * B` , but least common multiple of A and B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just want to use some equation to evaluate this thing rather than a
>   modulus operator because the program needs to produce results within 1
>   sec. I have tried this
>   `counter=(((int)(N/A))+((int)(N/B)))-((int)(N/(A*B)));` but it fails for
>   input N=200 A=20 B=8

You are already on the right track, your formula indicates you are trying to apply the inclusion-exclusion principle.

`(int) (N/A)` and `(int) (N/B)` corresponds to the counts of integers ≤ `N` that are dividable by `A` and `B`, respectively.

However, `(int) (N/(A*B))` **does not** give you the correct count of integers ≤ `N` that are *dividable by both `A` and `B`*.

In fact, you should replace `(int) (N/(A*B))` by `(int) (N/lcm(A,B))` in order to get the correct result. Here `lcm(A, B)` returns the *least common multiple of `A` and `B`*.

To implement the `lcm(A, B)` function, you can simply use the following formula:

```
lcm(A, B) = A * B / gcd(A, B);
```

where `gcd(A, B)` returns the *greatest common divisor of `A` and `B`*, and it can be efficiently computed by [Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), which inevitably involves using the modulus operator only very few times (`max {log(A), log(B)}` times to be precise), so there should not really be any performance issue for you.